# How to slow down a GameObject without slowing down the whole scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the GameObject Ball that uses physics (gravity).

I do apply some V3 forces to move it:

```
 ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = ballScript.dir * ballScript.force + vectorHeight;
```

Movement is quite ok. but it is just too quick for the player movement.

**Is there a way to slow the ball down?** (just the ball, not the whole scene)

Maths calculations does not seem ok: to slow it down, I need to increase the height and then ball's movement is not too realistic.

Comment: `ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = (ballScript.dir * ballScript.force + vectorHeight) * 0.5f;` ? Could you add more script context? What is `vectorHeight` for?

Comment: Please don't call `GetComponent` in `Update`, `FixedUpdate` unless you absolutely need to.

Comment: I usually add a "Speed" public field or serialized private field.  And use that to either slow or speed up the movement of my objects. From there you can choose to add the value or substract it... or use it as a "percent"... I is up to you

Comment: GetComponent  is not called in Update. 
I can add Speed... but since object reacts as Physical object, you cannot slow it down through Maths. Just imagine a REAL world tennis ball with a trajectory: you cannot slow it down without modifying its trajectory.

Comment: @yarek you can if you are in space though, but OP mentioned ofcourse it uses gravity ^^

Comment: You could probably use [this script](https://forum.unity.com/threads/why-does-rigidbody-3d-not-have-a-gravity-scale.440415/) which calculates the gravity "manually" on a per object base. this way your ball can simply pretend living in a different gravity space.

Comment: yes: this is a good point. I think it is impossible in real life to change speed of an object, keeping its trajectory without modifying the gravity. However is it possible in Unity 3D like modifying delta time or framefrate of an Object ?

Comment: you cant modify delta time without changing all objects in the entire scene, but if you wanted to slow down the object, just multiply your velocity by say, 0.5, and then multiply gravity and all other forces acting on the object by 0.5 as well

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this:**

```
 ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = (ballScript.dir * ballScript.force + vectorHeight)*Time.deltatime;
```

Comment: Velocity is calculated once only: at ball hit and not every frame !